Error: "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame2.!entry2"
I get the error "_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame2.!entry2". According to other threads about this error, this results from: "The error either means you've created more than one instance of Tk, or that you're trying to access a widget which has been destroyed."
So the entry-widget exists when I try to fill it with a path.
Can anyone help?
Here is my minimum working example:
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("800x700")
root.title(" abc ")

FFCframe = tk.Frame(root, width=600, height=100)
FFCframe.place(x=30,y=300)
FFCframe_sub1 = tk.Frame(FFCframe,width=120, height=100)
FFCframe_sub1.grid(row=0, column=0)
FFCframe_sub2 = tk.Frame(FFCframe,width=480, height=100)
FFCframe_sub2.grid(row=0, column=1)

te1_FFC3=tk.StringVar()
te1_FFC31=tk.StringVar()

#entry2_FFC_sub3 = tk.Entry (FFCframe_sub2, textvariable=te1_FFC3)
#entry2_FFC_sub31 = tk.Entry (FFCframe_sub2, textvariable=te1_FFC31)

def path(var):

    match var:

       case 4:
           filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
           entry2_FFC_sub3.insert("end",filename)
           return filename
       case 5:
           filename = filedialog.askopenfilename(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
           entry2_FFC_sub31.insert("end",filename)
           return filename

       case _:
            return 
    return

def change_FFC_frame(var):
    # destroy all widgets from frame
    for widget in FFCframe_sub2.winfo_children():
       widget.destroy()    
    label2_FFC = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc ", font=("Arial", 11))
    label2_FFC.place(x=0,y=0)    
    match var:
        
       case 1:
           if cb1_FFC.get()==True:
               label2_FFC_sub1 = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc", font=("Arial", 10))
               label2_FFC_sub1.place(x=10,y=50)
               cb2_FFC.set(False)
               cb3_FFC.set(False)
           cb2_FFC.set(False)
           cb3_FFC.set(False)
           return 
       case 2:
           if cb2_FFC.get()==True:
               label2_FFC_sub2 = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc          pixels", font=("Arial", 10))
               label2_FFC_sub2.place(x=10,y=30)
               te1_FFC2=tk.StringVar(value='40')
               entry2_FFC_sub2 = tk.Entry (FFCframe_sub2, textvariable=te1_FFC2)
               entry2_FFC_sub2.place(x=140,y=33,width="30")             
           cb1_FFC.set(False)
           cb3_FFC.set(False)
           return 
       case 3:
           if cb3_FFC.get()==True:
                label2_FFC_sub3 = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc", font=("Arial", 10))
                label2_FFC_sub3.place(x=10,y=35)
                button2_FFC_sub3 = tk.Button(FFCframe_sub2, text='File path',command = lambda: path(4))
                button2_FFC_sub3.place(x=150,y=35)
                te1_FFC3=tk.StringVar(value='')
                entry2_FFC_sub3 = tk.Entry (FFCframe_sub2, textvariable=te1_FFC3)
                entry2_FFC_sub3.place(x=210,y=38,width="200")
                label2_FFC_sub31 = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc", font=("Arial", 10))
                label2_FFC_sub31.place(x=10,y=65)
                button2_FFC_sub31 = tk.Button(FFCframe_sub2, text='File path',command = lambda: path(5))
                button2_FFC_sub31.place(x=150,y=65)
                te1_FFC31=tk.StringVar(value='')
                entry2_FFC_sub31 = tk.Entry (FFCframe_sub2, textvariable=te1_FFC31)
                entry2_FFC_sub31.place(x=210,y=68,width="200")
           cb1_FFC.set(False)
           cb2_FFC.set(False)
           return    
    return


cb1_FFC=tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
cb2_FFC=tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
cb3_FFC=tk.BooleanVar(value=False)
label1_FFC = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub1, text="abc:", font=('Arial',11))
label1_FFC.place(x=0,y=0)
checkb1_FFC = tk.Checkbutton(FFCframe_sub1, text='abc',variable=cb1_FFC, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=lambda:change_FFC_frame(1))
checkb1_FFC.place(x=10,y=30)
checkb2_FFC = tk.Checkbutton(FFCframe_sub1, text='abc',variable=cb2_FFC, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=lambda:change_FFC_frame(2))
checkb2_FFC.place(x=10,y=50)
checkb3_FFC = tk.Checkbutton(FFCframe_sub1, text='abc',variable=cb3_FFC, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, command=lambda:change_FFC_frame(3))
checkb3_FFC.place(x=10,y=70)
label2_FFC = tk.Label(FFCframe_sub2,text="abc ", font=("Arial", 11))
label2_FFC.place(x=0,y=0)


root.mainloop()

Many thanks in advance!
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\users\test tkinter verschachtelt.py", line 85, in <lambda>
    button2_FFC_sub31 = tk.Button(FFCframe_sub2, text='File path',command = lambda: path(5))
                                                                                    ^^^^^^^
  File "c:\users\test tkinter verschachtelt.py", line 40, in path
    entry2_FFC_sub31.insert("end",filename)
  File "C:\Users\anaconda3\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 3122, in insert
    self.tk.call(self._w, 'insert', index, string)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!frame.!frame2.!entry2"


Please edit the question to include the complete traceback message, so that we can see the exact execution path that led to the error.  The only problem I see at a quick glance is the line te1_FFC31=tk.StringVar(value='') inside change_FFC_frame() - that's a local variable you're assigning to, unrelated to the global variable of the same name, which seems unlikely to be what you intended.

Hi @jasonharper, thanks or your comment. I added the error message.

I don't see how that error could have come from the code you posted - the only global assignment to entry2_FFC_sub31 is commented out, so you should have got a NameError.  I'm going to assume that line was actually executed.  The problem is that the variable holds the original Entry; when you call change_FFC_frame(), all the widgets in that Frame are destroyed, and you might create a new Entry, but you assign it to a local variable named entry2_FFC_sub31, which vanishes at the end of the function.  So in path(), you're still trying to do something with the original, deleted Entry.

you may have to use global entry2_FFC_sub31 inside function to assign new value to external variable. Other idea is to create frames only once and later use pack() (or grid() to show them and .pack_forget() (or grid_forget()) to hide them - this way you don't have to destroy all widgets and create all again.

Hi jasonharber & furas thank you both very much. As sugested I was now able to solve the problem by defining the variables "entry2_FFC_sub31" and "entry2_FFC_sub3" as global inside the function "change_FFC_frame(var):". Is there a more elegant way?

Suggest to pass the StringVar associated to the required entry widget to path() instead of using global variable.
